# Do for loop in two parts

Tags: java, for-loop, dry

How would you write this in one for loop

```
for (File file:files)
  {
    if (file.getName().endsWith(".dat"))   {
       Species x = reader.readSpecies(file);
       allSpecies.add(x);
       allGenes.addAll(x.getGenome());
    }
} 
for (File file:files){
     if (file.getName().endsWith(".dat")) {
       Species x = reader.readSpecies(file);
       x.setIndices(allGenes);
     }
}
```

I want it to run through a for loop for one segment than the next using one loop. Is this possible? If not, is the code I am writing in violation of DRY?

Okay, no one who answered so far has understood my question at all. I want the code to go through the entire first loop. And then the entire second loop. the set indices method would not work until allGenes.addAll has been completed for ever file in the loop.

Comment: I do not understand why this question is upvoted at all.

Comment: +1 for the above comment, and the question was upvoted very quickly !

Comment: @MattBall I don't think you understood the question at all. neither did any of the people who answered

Comment: So if the code must be written like this in order to work at all, what's the question? This statement does not make sense to me: _"I want it to sun through a for loop for one segment than the next using one loop."_ Could you clarify?

Comment: You get more flies with honey that vinegar. If those who have answered have not understood your question, your question is faulty and therefore you should not berate those who are *trying to help*.

Comment: Then the answer to my question would be no, it isn't possible to do it in one loop. I didn't know it had to be written the way I wrote it in order to work and I was asking if it did. I had two lines of repeated code, and was taught that if lines are copied and pasted something could usually be changed for the better

Answer (score 2):

it should be

```
for (File file:files){
        if (file.getName().endsWith(".dat")){
            Species x = reader.readSpecies(file);                
            allSpecies.add(x);
            allGenes.addAll(x.getGenome());
            x.setIndices(allGenes);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (file.getName().endsWith(".dat")){
    Species x = reader.readSpecies(file);
    x.setIndices(allGenes); // Take out this line from for loop 2 and put it inside for loop 1
    allSpecies.add(x);
    allGenes.addAll(x.getGenome());
}
```

Since, your `if` condition in both the `for` loops are the same, you can merge both, by just moving the above mentioned statement from the second `for` to the first `for`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `x.setIndices(allGenes)` from the second loop into the first one after `allGenes.addAll(x.getGenome())`